# Pagination In MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I do pagination in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446196/how-do-i-do-pagination-in-asp-net-mvc)

Hii,

I want to add pagination to my view .

i am getting data from model as a list of users in the controller .

and in view i am displaying that from Model by inheriting IEnumarable..now

How can i inherit IPagelist overhere?

can anyone help me??

Comment: googling may help http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=pagination+in+asp.net+mvc+page

Answer (score 2):

What about passing the page number as an id to your Index action?
For example:

```
   public  ActionResult Index(int id)
   {
        var query = from x in y
                    select x;

        return View(query.Skip(id * 20).Take(20));
   }
```