# Ajax issue: delay in getting data from web service using innerHTML, please guide

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I am working on an ajax application which will display about a million records in an html table. Web service returns records from server, I build a logn string by concatinating data and tags and than put this string using innerHTML (not using DOM for getting better performance).

For testing I have put 6000 recods in database (stored procedure takes about 4 seconds in completion of its execution).

While testing on local system (database and application on same machine) it took about 5 minutes to display the records in page. After deplying on web server it did not responde even for more time. It looks very low performance. I put records in a CSV file and its weight was less than 2 MB. I couldn't understand why string concatinations to build html table and putting string in innerHTML is taking such a huge time (if it is the issue). Requiment is to show about million records in web page but performance on just 6000 records is disappointing. I am not gettign what to do to increase performance.

Kindly guide me and help me.

Comment: Are you doing the string concat on the service side or client side?

Comment: Coding Gorilla it is on client side

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to display a million records on a single page? No matter how you optimize your server code, that's a LOT of html to parse/render, especially if it's in a table.

Even using .innerHTML isn't going to "save" you any time. The rendering engine is still going to have to parse/style/render/position many millions of table rows/cells and you WILL have to wait while it's working.

If you absolutely HAVE to show all those records on a single page, try to break things up into manageable chunks. Have the AJAX call return (say) 100 records at a time, put those into the table, then fetch another 100 records, etc... At least that way you'll see the content of the page growing, rather than having to sit there and wait for 1,000,000 table rows to get displayed in a single shot.

A better option would be to do pageination, where only 100 records are shown at a time and you present a standard navigation with << first / prev / next / last >> buttons to swap through "pages" of data.

Answer (score 1):

As Marc stated, you need pagination. See if this helps - [How do I do pagination in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446196/how-do-i-do-pagination-in-asp-net-mvc)

In addition to this you could optimize the result by employing master-detail pattern - fetch only the summary of the record (master) and on some action in master, fetch details and display on the screen. This will reduce the size of data being transfered from the server.

Comment: thanks byte actually it is not a scenario where master-detail pattern can be used. There are just details records to show and no master records. Any more idea pleaes

Comment: In that case pagination is what you need. It could either be traditional page links based or you can device a strategy to fetch data asynchronously as the user scrolls through the list (i.e. continuos update on scroll)

Comment: One more thing, what format are you using for data transfer/exchange? Review this w.r.t xml, json, html etc