# C# Paginate SQL result from a proc call

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, model-view-controller, pagination

I have the following method that calls a proc in my database and returns the results into a dataset. The dataset is then used to populate a table I render using MVC & cshtml.

The method is:

```
public DataSet CallProcToDataSet(string procName)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UAT"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procName))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Connection = con;


            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                sda.Fill(ds);
            }
        }
    }

    return ds;
}
```

This works fine, however what I want is to have some way of paginating the results so that only 10 at a time are displayed. What is the best way for me to achieve this that doesn't involve any changes to the proc calls?

Comment: What pagination method you're currently using? This post can help you decide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446196/how-do-i-do-pagination-in-asp-net-mvc.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I'm not using any at the moment. But I'll take a look at the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this overload of the Fill method

```
public int Fill(int startRecord, int maxRecords, params DataTable[] dataTables);
```

(link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z5wy74x(v=vs.110).aspx)
This way you will only return a subset of the records without modifying your stored procedure.

Example (MSTest)

```
 [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            var procName = "sp_server_info";
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UAT"].ConnectionString;
            var tblName = "result";
            var tbls = new[] { ds.Tables.Add(tblName) };
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procName))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Connection = con;

                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        sda.Fill(0, 10, tbls);
                    }
                }
            }
            Assert.AreEqual(tbls[0].Rows.Count, 10);

        }
```

Comment: Thank you. What would then be the best way to render the page option? Like if I had 100 records, I should have 10 pages with the ability to go between. What would you suggest?

Comment: You're welcome, I would ask a separate question about that by specifying that you already have paging at data layer level.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i += 10)
            {
                DataTable pageTable = dt.AsEnumerable().Where((x, n) => (n >= i) && (n < i + 10)).CopyToDataTable();
            }
```

Comment: Wouldn't a `skip` and `take` be easier?

Comment: OP hasn't decided which pagination method to use yet. So it is possible to use other methods like `Skip` & `Take`.

Comment: I just thought of Where() method first.

Comment: @jdweng placed the datatable and for statement before i return my dataset at the end of my method but no pagination is happening.

Comment: You code needs to be changed to allow looping.  I just did a very simple example of how to get 10 rows at a time.  I don't think you want to keep on querying the database every time you want the next 10 rows so you need to add a new method for paging through the table.