# how to get two item from a List<> in every get request in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I get two value per get request from a `List<>`, For example,
I have a `Person List<>` with six `Person` Ordered by ID in that `List<>` now in every get request using `JQuery ajax()` I want to get only two item from the `list<>`, first request will return `Person` with `ID 1 & 2`, second request will return `Person` with `ID 3 & 4`, and so forth.

I've tried

```
public IEnumerable<PersonViewModel> GetAllStudents()
    {
        IEnumerable<Person> dbPersons = _repo.getPersons().OrderBy(s => s.ID).Take(2);

        List<PersonViewModel> persons = new List<PersonViewModel>();
        foreach(var p in dbPersons)
        {
            persons.Add(MapDbPieToPersonViewModel(p));
        }

        return persons;
    }
```

But this only return first two item.

Comment: Why would it ever return anything other than first two? You always take first two. Need to pass start point and skip to that

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380413/paging-with-linq-for-objects

Comment: And the more mvc-specific https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446196/how-do-i-do-pagination-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Enumerable.Skip(Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public IEnumerable<PersonViewModel> GetAllStudents(int page)
{
    const int PageSize = 2;
    IEnumerable<Person> dbPersons = _repo.getPersons().OrderBy(s => s.ID).Skip(page * PageSize).Take(PageSize);

    List<PersonViewModel> persons = new List<PersonViewModel>();
    foreach(var p in dbPersons)
    {
        persons.Add(MapDbPieToPersonViewModel(p));
    }

    return persons;
}
```

Comment: thanks, how can I pass the `page` from my ajax(), I'm new to ajax().

Comment: by adding `?page=X` to the query string