# Multiple pages with a table list from db

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a list of products in a table on db. I got them on a single page with this code:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    var products = productsRepository.GetAll();
    IEnumerable<Models.Product> productsView = products.Select(p => new Models.Product() {
        Id = p.Id,
        Category = p.Category.Name,
        Brand = p.Brand,
        Name = p.Name,
        Type = p.Type,
        IsActive = p.IsActive,
        SellPrice = p.SellPrice,
        AddedDate = p.AddedDate
    });
    return View(productsView);
}
```

How should i get 'n' products per page and have multiple pages ? 
Ty

Comment: What you're looking for is `pagination`. Here's an older Stack overflow post which explains how to do it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446196/how-do-i-do-pagination-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

Solve it . I changed to a ienumerable and i had an error on the redirect page but all works well now. Thank u
EDIT: 
At the very start my index with paginating was looking like this

```
    public ActionResult Index(int page = 0)
    {

        var products = productsRepository.GetAll();



        const int PageSize = 5; // you can always do something more elegant to set this

        var count = productsView.Count();

        var data = products.OrderBy(o=>o.Brand).Skip(page * PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList();

        this.ViewBag.MaxPage = (count / PageSize) - (count % PageSize == 0 ? 1 : 0);

        this.ViewBag.Page = page;

        return this.View(data);
    }
```

My view was expecting something of type i enumerable so after i added this everything was fine.

```
IEnumerable<Models.Product> productsView = products.Select(p => new Models.Product()
        {
            Id = p.Id,
            Category = p.Category.Name,
            Brand = p.Brand,
            Name = p.Name,
            Type = p.Type,
            IsActive = p.IsActive,
            SellPrice = p.SellPrice,
            AddedDate = p.AddedDate

        });
```

I m a begginer so im struggling a lot with these kind of things

Comment: You changed what to `IEnumerable`? You should post what you've fixed, so that future readers can benefit if they have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're using different types, in one place you're using `BarHelper.Domain.Product` and another `BarHelper.Areas.Admin.Models.Product`. So, make sure you're passing the same type.