# Compression scheme between C# and Angular or zip functionality in Angular 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api, angular7

I need to transfer Large amount of Json file content from the server side to Angular side.

I am using Web api(c#) as the back end Angular 7 as the font end.

Json file is around 20 MB. So I have compressed the Json file using LZ compression from the server and I could able to decompress the file from the Angular website.

But the file size after the LZ compression is still around 8 MB. I need to make it to more smaller file. Can anyone recommend better compression scheme so that I can reduce the file size and transfer file from the server side to Angular side.?

Also can I zip those compressed file from the server , then transfer it to the client side and unzip those LZ compressed file from the Angular side?

Comment: This is the same off-topic post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59718440/best-compression-scheme-between-c-sharp-and-angular-or-zip-functionality-in-angu). Misspelled words, and everything.

Comment: Why this is off topic? We need some technology help from stack overflaw members

Comment: Json format is not suitable for large data transfer. Can you make your request result filtered on the service side?

Comment: Hi Oleska, Thanks for the response. Could you please recommend any other format for the large file transfer?

Comment: there is no "silver bullet" technology unfortunately to put 20MB in one second. You can use [pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446196/how-do-i-do-pagination-in-asp-net-mvc) to transfer only part of the data.But first of all you have to check how those data are processed on the client. Do you really need raw data to be send over network? Can you add some processing code on the server side to filter or to pre-process data before sending over the network?