# Paging in MVC .NET Framework not working, how to get it to work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, paging

I try to convert an old asp.net webforms application to an MVC application using Entity Framework. I generated the model for this application using the scaffold-DbContect command which is part of the EF Core Tools. I was able to generate a list of items. In this case, I'm converting an old issuetracker system. The list is a list of the registered bugs. But this is quite a long list (5K+ records), so I would like to add paging. I came across [this item on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446196/how-do-i-do-pagination-in-asp-net-mvc) and the third answer looked like it could work for me.

So I added the next code to my controller index-action

```
  public ActionResult Index(int page = 0)
    {

        int pageSize = 10;

        var qry = db.Bugs
        .Include(e => e.Organization)
        .Include(e => e.AssignedUser)
        .Include(e => e.UpdatedUser)
        .Include(e => e.ReportedUser)
        .Include(e => e.Project)
        .Include(e => e.Category)
        .Include(e => e.Status)
        .Include(e => e.Priority)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .AsQueryable();

        var count = qry.Count();

        var data = qry.Skip(page * pageSize).Take(pageSize).OrderBy(e => e.BgId);

        this.ViewBag.MaxPage = (count / pageSize) - (count % pageSize == 0 ? 1 : 0);

        this.ViewBag.Page = page;

        return View(data.ToList());
    }
```

The problem is, I get no results. If I debug the data var has a count of 10, but there is no output.
If I don't filter and just use qry.ToList() in my return View() I get all the records. No exception is thrown either. What am I missing? Anybody a clue? I think I overlook something.

Comment: ViewBag is messy... bind the model.  (And use PagedList helper class/function!)  You can add it straight from VS dependency manager.  You'll end up with items in your model (.cs file) that store things like page#, results per page, sort, etc... anything relating to saved view state...

Comment: Model Binding: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: for your question though, I think it's because you've got a var there (compiler decides the type)... try with var data = qry.Skip(page * pageSize).Take(pageSize).OrderBy(e => e.BgId).ToList();  I think "ToList()" will make the query actually run instead of being deferred.

Comment: `.AsQueryable()` is not needed. `OrderBy` should be placed before `Skip`. Also update question with actual generated query. If problem still exists, try to comment out Includes one by one.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv thank you for the reply but based on the previous comment I choose to use the PageListed helper which is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @pcalkins I could solve my problem using the PageList.mvc helper.

I ended up with the next code in my Action:

```
  // GET: Bugs
    public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
        var qry = db.Bugs
        .Include(e => e.Organization)
        .Include(e => e.AssignedUser)
        .Include(e => e.UpdatedUser)
        .Include(e => e.ReportedUser)
        .Include(e => e.Project)
        .Include(e => e.Category)
        .Include(e => e.Status)
        .Include(e => e.Priority)
        .OrderBy(e => e.BgId).ToList();

        int pageSize = 20;
        int pageNumber = page ?? 1;

        return View(qry.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
```

I had to change the view to get it to work with this PageList helper in:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<IssueTracker.Models.Bugs>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Issuelist";
}
<div class="container pt-5">
    <div class="pb-2">
        <form action="" class="form-inline">
            @Html.ActionLink("Add", "Create", "Bugs", null, new { @class = "btn btn-success mr-sm-2" })
            <div class="form-group mr-sm-2">
                <select class="custom-select">
                    <option selected="">Open this select menu</option>
                    <option value="1">One</option>
                    <option value="2">Two</option>
                    <option value="3">Three</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-sm-2">
                <i class="fa fa-print"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-sm-2">
                <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover tauw-table table-sm" id="tauw-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">
                        ID
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        Description
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        Reported by
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col" style="width:120px">
                        Reported on
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        Status
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        Priority
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        Organisation
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        Category
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        Project
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BgId)
                        </th>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BgShortDesc)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReportedUser.UsUsername)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BgReportedDate)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status.StName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Priority.PrName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Organization.OgName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.CtName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Project.PjName)
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:50px;">
                            <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Bugs",new { id = item.BgId })" class="fa fa-edit"></a>
                            <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Bugs",new { id = item.BgId })" class="fa fa-trash"></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br />
        Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
        new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
</div>
```

I couldn't get it to work right away. It only showed me sometimes one record sometimes 4, very unpredictable. When I tried debugging I saw an error like: "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first." When I searched for an answer I came across [this](https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/20693216/there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-connection-which-must-be-closed-first-plus-asp-net-mvc) site which suggested using the ToList() function with the include() options. This solved my problem for the paging. Hope this can help others as well.